# Return data from multiple tables via a Stored Procedure of MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core

I have been trying to return data from multiple tables from a single stored procedure. And the stored procedure is in  MySQL.

But I have not been able to get all the details inside of the table. Can anyone tell me what am I missing in this case?
Also, do I have to mention some more details here?

The stored procedure can be found below.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetFormListData`()
BEGIN

    -- SQLINES LICENSE FOR EVALUATION USE ONLY

    Select * from MealType;

    -- SQLINES LICENSE FOR EVALUATION USE ONLY

    Select * from RoomBedType;

    -- SQLINES LICENSE FOR EVALUATION USE ONLY

    Select * from RoomCoolingType;

    -- SQLINES LICENSE FOR EVALUATION USE ONLY

    Select * from RoomRent;

    -- SQLINES LICENSE FOR EVALUATION USE ONLY

    Select * from RoomType;

END
```

And my c# .Net code can be found below.

```
public async Task<object> GetFormListDetails()
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"Server=Localhost;Database=HotelManagement;Uid=root;Pwd=Onkar@123;");
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetFormListData", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                MySqlDataReader i = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                var data = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                while (i.Read())
                {
                    var myString = i.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    return await Task.FromResult(new ResponseModel(ResponseCode.OK, myString, null));
                }
                i.Close();
                
                con.Close();
                return await Task.FromResult(new ResponseModel(ResponseCode.Error, "", "Faild to add data"));
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(new ResponseModel(ResponseCode.Error, ex.Message, null));
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you have multiple resultsets in your read use [NextResult()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) to advance to the next set. With that being said, I don't think this will really help you unless you change a lot more code. At present you are selecting every single value from 5 tables, and all you do is take the first column from the first row of the first table and return it, so you only use a tiny fraction of the data you are querying. Furthermore calling `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` is also redundant.

Comment: @GarethD , so what all changes do you recommend? I would like to fetch all the columns of all the 5 tables (each table has a different count of columns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public async Task<object> GetFormListDetails()
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                MySqlDataReader myReader;
                using (var con = new MySqlConnection(@"Server=Localhost;Database=HotelManagement;Uid=root;Pwd=Onkar@123;"))
                {
                    con.Open();

                    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                    adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("GetFormListData", con);
                    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    adapter.Fill(dataset);
                }

                return new JsonResult(dataset);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

this is catered for your query, also you will need to install NewtonSoft Json from NuGet Package Manager if you don't have it already.